# counting the number of possible results

Tags: combinatorics

It's a game I've seen and I know the algorithmic solution, but does it have a mathematical solution?

> You have a list of numbers 1-3 (for example) and two operators -,+. How many results can I get when combining all the possible number and the operators knowing that you can reverse the number and the operators?

For example I can get 1+3=4 or 2-1=1 or 1-2=-1.

Answer (score 0):

For addition since commutative you have $3 \choose 2$ choices, for subtraction you have $3 \cdot 2$.